# Function Arguments in C

Tags: c, arguments

I'm totally new to C. Here's the question:

> Write the function
>
> ```
> fzero(double f(double),double x1, double x2)
> ```
>
> as we did in class and use it to find all the solutions of
>
> ```
> sin( pi*x / (1+x^2) ) = 0.25.
> ```

Now, I don't want you to solve the this. I'd missed this lecture and only want to understand what means

```
double f(double);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In that context, it means that `f` is a **function pointer** to a function to that takes one `double` argument, and returns a `double`.

As an example:

```
void foo(double f(double))
{
    double y = f(3.0);  // Call function through function pointer
    printf("Output = %f\n", y);   // Prints "Output = 9.0000"
}

double square(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}

int main(void)
{
    foo(&square);  // Pass the address of square()
}
```

Note that there are two syntaxes for function pointers:

```
void foo(double f(double))
void foo(double (*f)(double))
```

These are equivalent.